# How to get node and select children nodes using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xml similar to the one below:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Document>
    <name>SMTH</name>
    <Group>
        <GroupHeader>Some Description</GroupHeader>
        <Port>
            <ID>13553</PortID>
            <Name>Some name</PortName>
            <Number>PO1005</WorldPortNumber>
            <Section>
                <SectionHeader ID="63">General overview</SectionHeader>
                <PAR ID="59341" updatedate="19/05/2010 08:35:51">Important data</PAR>
            </Section>
            <Section>
                <SectionHeader ID="66">Max size</SectionHeader>
                <PAR ID="59344" updatedate="19/05/2010 08:35:51">Important data</PAR>
            </Section>
        </Port>
    </Group>
</Document>
```

I would like to select all the Port nodes including **only** ID, Name, Number and PAR children nodes (rest of the children node should be ignored). Result should be just a collection of Port nodes including those 4 children nodes I listed above. 
Here is what is should look like:

```
Port:
    ID=234234
    Name=blabla
    Number=324234
    PAR=sdfsdfs
    PAR=fgfgfg
Port:
    ID=5555
    Name=blabla
    Number=ghfh
    PAR=sdfsdfs
    PAR=fgfgfg
...
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I think I'll try xslt transformation but to be clear about what I want to achieve is that I would like to get xml something like:
<Port>
<ID />
<Name />
<Number /><PAR /></Port>...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somthing like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Port">
  <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()='ID' or name()='Name' or name()='Number']"></xsl:copy-of>
  <xsl:copy-of select="Section/*[name()='PAR']"></xsl:copy-of>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hope that helps. :)

Regards,
Harrie

Comment: My example result should also be xml. The way I wrote it is only the overview of how the hierarchy should look like. The result should be then something like that:
<Port><ID /><Name /><Number /><PAR /></Port>...

Answer (score 1):

What you request is impossible to achieve with a single XPath expression.

An XPath expression selects a node or nodeset *as it exists in the document*.  If you use XPath to select a `Port` element, then that element will be returned to you unmodified, with all of its existing document context, including its parent and children.

You could select each of the descendent elements independently of `Port`, using a union `|`, or, you could select each of the `Port` elements, then with each `Port` as the context, select only those descendants you want to use (or remove/ignore those descendents you don't want).

How you do this will depend on what you intend to do with the nodes when you have retrieved them.  If you wish to produce the example output from the input, then XSLT may be a good choice.